# Text list to excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, csv, text, vba

I'm trying to figure out a way to convert a text list formatted in the way below to an excel spreadsheet with single headers for each key. Would I have to make code that combines columns based on header names? I've searched google and can't find anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

*text list*

```
Item No: Baklawa 001
Description: Jasmine Mixed Baklawa Tray
Barcode: 777640001048
Size: 1x320 g

Item No: Baklawa 002
Description: Jasmine Mixed Baklawa Tray
Barcode: 777640001031
Size: 1x725 g

Item No: Baklawa021
Description: Jasmine Baklawa Roll
Barcode:
Size: 40 pcs

Item No: Baklawa041
Description: Jasmine Baklawa Almond (Square)
Barcode:
Size: 40 pcs
```

*end text list*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more easily accomplished in Word, if that's a possibility.  You can use it create a tab-separated list, and then put that into Excel.

Assuming the text formatting in your example is accurate, the macro below will perform the desired conversion.  You could also search/replace manually.

```
Sub LineZapper()
   Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="Item No: ", ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="^pDescription: ", ReplaceWith:="^t", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="^pBarcode: ", ReplaceWith:="^t", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="^pBarcode:", ReplaceWith:="^t", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="^pSize: ", ReplaceWith:="^t", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="^p^p", ReplaceWith:="^p", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

I created two instances to replace the "`Barcode:`" lines because in the text sample where there's no barcode data, there's no trailing space like the others have.

Note that if there are preexisting tabs in your text list, it will throw off the import to Excel.  If that's the case, the first step should be a search/replace to eliminate them.

It's easy enough to manually insert a header row later.

Comment: This is great! Thanks.